# What is $\Re(e^i)$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

> What is $\Re(e^i)$?

My book says answer is $e$.  Can that be right?

I know $e^{i \pi} = \cos \pi + i \sin \pi = -1$

So that would mean $e^i = \cos 1 + i \sin 1$ and the real part would be $\cos 1$.  That's not the book's answer.

Comment: You're right...

Comment: Let $x=1$ in 
$$e^{ix} = \cos(x)+i \sin(x)$$

Comment: what book is this?

Comment: For what it's worth, Wolfram Alpha agrees with you. `Re[E^I]`

Answer (score 7):

You're right, $e^i=\cos 1+i \sin 1$. So the answer is $\cos 1$.